# To open a created java project from a javacode

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have created a java project via this syntax,

```
   IProject project= root.getProject(projectName);
   IJavaProject jproject= JavaCore.create(project);   
   System.out.println(jproject);
```

and i am getting output as "jproject (not open)",
can anyone please tell me how to **open** this created project via a java code.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the project and why is the project not being open a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't need to open the Java project as the Java Model Manager will do this as required when you use the project.

You can test if a `IJavaProject` is open using:

```
IJavaProject javaProject = ....

boolean isOpen = javaProject.isOpen();
```

and if it is not open use:

```
javaProject.open(progressMonitor);
```

to open it. `progressMonitor` is an `IProgressMonitor` or you can specify `null` if you don't want progress to be reported.